# Discord.py Which module should I use aiomysql or mysql-connector?

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

Am creating a discord bot for which I chose mysql for the database because of it's versatility, scalability and other factors for which it's famous.

Now the question arises which module should I use for mysql, `aiomysql` or `mysql-connector`? I know that discord works completely using functions provided by asyncio, so, I chose to use aiomysql at first but a problem arises during my testing phase which am gonna discuss with you all.

Just for testing, that maybe there can be some case where multiple users or functions access a same table in database at the same time, so to check the efficiency of the bot, I tried locking a table through the mysql terminal, and then accessing that table through a command. So, as expected it started waiting for that table to be unlocked. But the problem arises when I executed a second command which is a random command which has no relation with that database, but as I executed that, this message pops up `Task was destroyed but it is pending!` and that statement in first command waiting for database never executed even when I unlocked the table.

So, now am confused what should I use? If I use `mysql-connector` then the second command will wait for rest of the waiting commands [First command in this case which is waiting for the table to be unlocked] to fulfilled first then it'll be executed which is making it longer to respond to the command.

And If I use `aiomysql` then in a case where multiple functions are updating a table at the same time, issue like this can occur where a task is destroyed. Please share your views on this in comments. Thanks!

Comment: Usually it is not, or only very rarely, necessary to lock a table. transactions help. to see the problem you have to show some code

Comment: Well my main question was which module should I use aiomysql or mysql-connector for a discord bot?

Comment: This kind of question is off-topic for StackOverflow @Shubham